# Remove top and bottom margin in tabular (around lists)

Tags: tables, margins, itemize, enumitem

If I create a table with several (short) lists, currently I'm using a table construction with enumitem to (almost) remove the left margin. Now I still have a rather large margin at the top and the bottom (above and below) of the itemize lists.

Is there any way I can instruct either the itemize list or the table to remove this margin as well?

Code example:

```
\begin{tabular}{|m{3cm}|p{5.5cm}|p{5.5cm}|}
   \hline
    Category 2 &
    \begin{itemize}[leftmargin=*]
        \item A
        \item B
    \end{itemize} &
    \begin{itemize}[leftmargin=*]
        \item C
        \item F
    \end{itemize} \\
   \hline
\end{tabular}
```

Comment: Is there a reason why you need a list environment inside `tabular`? For example, you could just use `\textbullet~A` and separate them by `\par` or even `\\`? It will give a tight spacing yes seem to be list-like.

Comment: Using the `nolistsep` option for the inner `itemize` environments helps, but will still leave some space.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Here are some options to work with, as alternative to using a list inside a `tabular`:

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{array}% http://ctan.org/pkg/array
\usepackage{enumitem}% http://ctan.org/pkg/enumitem
\begin{document}
Original: \par
\begin{tabular}{|m{3cm}|p{5.5cm}|p{5.5cm}|}
   \hline
    Category 2 &
    \begin{itemize}[leftmargin=*]
        \item A Here is some text that should wrap inside the list
        \item B Here is some text that should wrap inside the list
    \end{itemize} &
    \begin{itemize}[leftmargin=*]
        \item C Here is some text that should wrap inside the list
        \item D Here is some text that should wrap inside the list
    \end{itemize} \\
   \hline
\end{tabular}

\verb|\textbullet| option: \par
\begin{tabular}{|m{3cm}|p{5.5cm}|p{5.5cm}|}
   \hline
    Category 2 &
    \textbullet~A Here is some text that should wrap inside the list \par
    \textbullet~B Here is some text that should wrap inside the list &
    \textbullet~C Here is some text that should wrap inside the list \par
    \textbullet~F Here is some text that should wrap inside the list \\
   \hline
\end{tabular}

Nested \verb|tabular| option: \par
\begin{tabular}{|m{3cm}|l|l|}
   \hline
    Category 2 &
    \begin{tabular}{@{\textbullet~}p{5cm}@{}}
      A Here is some text that should wrap inside the list \\
      B Here is some text that should wrap inside the list
    \end{tabular} &
    \begin{tabular}{@{\textbullet~}p{5cm}@{}}
      C Here is some text that should wrap inside the list \\
      F Here is some text that should wrap inside the list
    \end{tabular} \\
   \hline
\end{tabular}
\end{document}​
```

It is possible to modify the last option to be exactly `5.5cm` in width. The above example merely illustrates list alternatives that adhere to tight spacing while simulating the list look/feel.

Comment: Thanks for showing me these options, as I'm quite a latex newbie, I did not know about the textbullet option which seems quite appropriate for my usage. :-)

Comment: And there are no other options using the itemize environment? The textbullet option does not work to indent multiline entries, and creating a table is rather cumbersome... thank you!

Comment: @strauberry: You can use `itemize` and play with the vertical spacing lengths.