# Remove vertical spacing from top/bottom of itemize environment within a table

Tags: tables, spacing, itemize, enumitem

I'd like to create compact itemized lists within a column of a table that are vertically alligned with non-itemized text from the same column. I'm using `enumitem` to get more control over these environments, but I can't figure out how to completely remove the vertical spacing above and below the `itemize` environment.

Consider this simple example:

```
\documentclass[12pt]{report}
\usepackage{enumitem}
\usepackage{booktabs}

\begin{document}

\begin{tabular}{p{3cm}p{3cm}}
\toprule
Column one & Column two \\
\midrule
First group &
\begin{itemize}[noitemsep,topsep=0ex,partopsep=0ex,leftmargin=2ex]
\item First item
\item Second item
\end{itemize} \\
Second group &
\begin{itemize}[noitemsep,topsep=0ex,partopsep=0ex,leftmargin=2ex]
\item First item
\item Second item
\end{itemize} \\
\bottomrule
\end{tabular}

\end{document}
```

[image: output]

I have set `topsep` and `partopsep` to zero to try and remove the vertical spacing, but this does not seem to work as expected. Is there additional spacing outside the `itemize` environment that I'm overlooking?

Comment: Possible duplicate: [Remove top and bottom margin in `tabular` (around lists)](http://tex.stackexchange.com/q/63964/5764)

Comment: I know I've answered a question like this before, too. Maybe http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/160834/how-to-create-a-specific-table-in-latex?

Comment: Thanks @Werner the nested `tabular` option seems to be working as expected

Answer (score 1):

I found the best approach was to using a nested `tabular` approach, shown in [this answer](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/63969/2951).

Here is an adaptation to a slightly modified example:

```
\documentclass[12pt]{report}
\usepackage{booktabs}
\usepackage[raggedrightboxes]{ragged2e}

\begin{document}

\begin{tabular}{p{3cm}p{3cm}}
\toprule
Column one & Column two \\
\midrule
First group &
  \begin{tabular}[t]{@{\textbullet~}p{3cm}@{}}
    First item \\
    Second item
  \end{tabular} \\
Second group &
  \begin{tabular}[t]{@{\textbullet~}p{3cm}@{}}
    First item \\
    Second item, now with a longer description
  \end{tabular} \\
\bottomrule
\end{tabular}

\end{document}
```

[image: output]